# Getting "Read Timed Out" exception frequently for last few days on my already running SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, connectivity

Our client has a setup of 2 VMs . One of them has SQLServer 2008 R2 and other has a Java utility which I am using to update the Database..

It was working some time back, but recently it started giving "Read Timed Out". It gives this error at different point of time after I run the utility so I dont think it is query time out.

IT team of the client do not recall anything changed recently to the server.
There is also no firewall as per them.

I have checked the even logs and there are bunch of following errors :

> 2014-05-27 11:21:39.82 Logon       Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State:
>   38.
>   2014-05-27 11:21:39.82 Logon       Login failed for user 'xxxx'. Reason: Failed to open the explicitly specified database. [CLIENT:
>   192.168.32.38]

however I checked that the utility is not using the username specified in the above error. It is instead using default 'sa' credential.

And more importantly the above error did not trigger when I ran the utility, but I think it could be something related to SQL Server performance so pasted it.

I checked that "AUTO_CLOSE" is false for the DB. Utility at the end gives the error "Connection Already Closed" as I try to close the connection in the finally block.

I am using

```
validationQuery = select 1 as dbcp_connection_test
testOnBorrow = true
maxIdle = 40
```

I get connected to the DB in the starting part of the utility, but get the below error anywhere between 5 seconds to 90 seconds.

I have tried using IP instead of hostname but no difference.

There is one more application connecting to another DB on same server, and that is working fine, so I think it should be something specific to this DB/Connection .

I also checked in my utility logs, the connection closing code is not executed until I get the below error, so I think after I connect to SQLServer somehow connection is getting killed/dropped from the server side.

Here is the error:

> [java] 06-Jun-2014 10:08:32
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement close
>        [java] WARNING: SQLServerPreparedStatementID:15965 ( ConnectionID:6 TransactionID:0x0600000040000000): Error (ignored)
>   closing PreparedHandle:0
>        [java] com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Read timed out
>        [java]   at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.terminate(Unknown
>   Source)
>        [java]   at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel.read(Unknown Source)
>        [java]   at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSReader.readPacket(Unknown Source)
>        [java]   at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSReader.readPacket(Unknown Source)
>        [java]   at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.startResponse(Unknown Source)
>        [java]   at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.startResponse(Unknown Source)
>        [java]   at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement$1PreparedHandleClose.doExecute(Unknown
>   Source)
>        [java]   at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(Unknown Source)
>        [java]   at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(Unknown
>   Source)
>        [java]   at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeCommand(Unknown
>   Source)
>        [java]   at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.closePreparedHandle(Unknown
>   Source)
>        [java]   at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.close(Unknown
>   Source)
>        [java]   at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingStatement.close(DelegatingStatement.java:152)

Comment: Does the account running your utility has proper access to the database ? Is the Login properly Mapped to the database that it is trying to access ?